# Puppet: Git installation for windows timeout

Tags: windows, git, puppet

I have the following resources to install git on our windows server CI servers(don't need tortoisehg). It seems that is going for timeout even though the installation completes successfully. I have tried using the chocolatey cinst command but it is the same thing. Any other way how to install git on windows with puppet.

```
file { $pkg:
  ensure => present,
  name   => 'C:\Temp\Git-1.8.1.2-preview20130201.exe',
  source => 'puppet:///puppetfs/Git-1.8.1.2-preview20130201.exe',
  mode   => '0755',
  before => Exec[$pkg]
}

exec { $pkg:
  creates   => 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin',
  command   => 'C:\Windows\sysnative\cmd.exe /c "C:\Temp\Git-1.8.1.2-preview20130201.exe /silent"',
  logoutput => true,
  timeout   => 900
}
```

It seems that the process can't complete and stays on the process explorer forever.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with this command line

```
  command   => 'C:\Windows\sysnative\cmd.exe /k "C:\Temp\Git-1.8.1.2-preview20130201.exe /SP- /NORESTART /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /SAVEINF="C:\Temp\git-settings.txt" /LOG="C:\Temp\git-installer.log"',
```